# Get index of object in Generic/List based on value of a property

Tags: powershell, properties, indexof, generic-list

I can populate a `Generic.List` with instances of my class, each with a unique value in the ID property, like this.

```
$packages = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::New()

class Package {
    # Properties
    [String]$ID

    # Constructor
    Package ([String]$id) {
        $this.ID = $id
    }
}

foreach ($i in 65..90) {
    $packages.Add([Package]::New("$([char]$i)"))
}
```

Now I want to get the index of a particular item, along the lines of `$packages.IndexOf('C')`. But doing this in C# seems to require the use of a lambda, and PowerShell doesn't seem to support that. I would rather not have to initialize my own index variable and iterate through all the items in the list checking their IDs and incrementing the index along the way. But, maybe this is that grey area between using PowerShell with only native PS cmdlets and just using C#, where you miss out on the sugar in both extremes and have to make your own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `[scriptblock]` as a predicate:

```
$packages.FindIndex({$args[0].ID -eq 'C'})
# or
$packages.FindIndex({param($item) $item.ID -eq 'C'})
```

---

Assuming your package IDs are unique, consider using a dictionary instead of a list:

```
$packages = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,Package]]::new([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

class Package {
    # Properties
    [String]$ID

    # Constructor
    Package ([String]$id) {
        $this.ID = $id
    }
}

foreach ($i in 65..90) {
    $ID = "$([char]$i)"
    $packages.Add($ID, [Package]::new($ID))
}
```

Now you don't need to worry about the position of the item, anymore, now you can simply remove one by ID:

```
$wasRemoved = $packages.Remove("C")
```

`Remove()` returns `$true` when it successfully removes an entry, `$false` when the key wasn't found

Comment: Aha. I had found some info on using a script block like that, but it wasn't for this specific use case, and it didn't work. Not because the script block approach doesn't work, but because you need to use FindIndex. Doh!

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to look for method signatures that take delegates (`System.Predicate`, `System.Func` etc.) as arguments :)

Comment: I am learning a LOT as I try to get my head around classes. Now I need to figure out how to `.RemoveAt()` multiple times, which is why I needed the index. I'll bang my head on that for an hour or so before I come back again. ;-)

Comment: @Gordon Sounds like you could benefit from organizing your objects in a dictionary rather than a list

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen That's a good point. It would simplify my data validation too, as now I have to test to see if there are duplicate IDs, with an ordered dictionary I can just try/catch. I think I'll play with that now actually. Thanks!