# Find element in [Generic.List[Hashtable]] based on value of hash table key, then remove from list

Tags: powershell

Given a `[Generic.List[Hashtable]]` of the following form

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Hashtable]]::new()
$list.Add(@{
    id = 'one'
    data = 'first'
})
$list.Add(@{
    id = 'two'
    data = 'second'
})
$list.Add(@{
    id = 'three'
    data = 'third'
})
```

I can find a particular entry, say `id='two'`, like this

```
$target = $list.Where({$_.id -eq 'two'})
```

However, I then need to delete this element. As far as I can tell the only way to delete is by index, and when I try to use the same predicate like so

```
$list.FindIndex({$_.id -eq 'two'})
```

I get back -1, I assume Not Found. I also tried

```
$list.FindIndex($target)
```

and that produces an error. Not a surprise since all the signatures expect a predicate of some sort.

Well, drat. Apparently I asked about finding indexes a few years ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61985578/get-index-of-object-in-generic-list-based-on-value-of-a-property). And while not mentioned specifically there, it would appear that the automatic variable `$_` doesn't work here, but `$args[0]` does.

```
$list.RemoveAt($list.FindIndex({$args[0].id -eq 'two'}))
```

Comment: To be able to use a variable name inside one of the .net methods (like .FindIndex), you can define a param like this: `$list.FindIndex({param($item) $item.id -eq 'two'})`. Doesn't make much of a difference, but makes your code a bit more readable :)

Comment: @daves I am curious, what exactly is populating that $item parameter? Is it just automatically each item in the list? I ask because I am now trying to prefix every item in a list, which I could do with an array with `$array.Foreach({"prefix $PSItem"})`, but trying to do that with a list with `$list.Foreach({param($item) "_ $item"})` does not work.

Comment: The `$list.FindIndex` method allows you to set the parameter name in what's called a 'predicate' in .Net, because `$list` is [a .Net object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-6.0), and `FindIndex` is one of its methods. .Net lists also have [a Foreach method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-6.0), but it doesn't take a 'predicate' - it takes a 'delegate'. A predicate is like a delegate but it returns a boolean. A delegate needs you to specify what to do with the item...

Comment: For example, `$list.Foreach({param($item) Write-host "prefix $item"})

Comment: @daves Interesting. I was somewhat on the right track then, but what I want to do is return the revised list, like I can do with an array. To that end I tried `$list.Foreach({param($item) "prefix $item"})`, which returns nothing. I also tried `$list.Foreach({param($item) return "prefix $item"})` with the same result. So how would I get the prefixed values back as another list?

Comment: I think the answer is that delegates don't have a return value, so nothing comes back to the powershell pipe. Lists have a `GetEnumerator()` method, which through what I assume is powershell magic, has a `ForEach()` method even though [it's not there in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.enumerator?view=net-6.0). Maybe powershell converts enumerators to arrays? Anyway, `$list.GetEnumerator().Foreach({"prefix $_"})` works and returns a modified array. And if you need it be a list again, just cast it.

Comment: So, a little surprised that casting required also wrapping the results in `@()`, like so `$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@($list.GetEnumerator().Foreach({"prefix $PSItem"}))`. That works a treat. I may need to play with performance profiling a bit, since all this casting may argue against. But I suspect I won't be doing it on more than a few hundred elements, which shouldn't be too bad. And in the process learned some more C#ish stuff, so... cool.

Comment: Looks like the `enumerator.foreach` returns an `[iCollection]`: `($list.GetEnumerator().Foreach({"prefix $PSItem"})) -is [System.Collections.ICollection]` returns `True`. You can cast it back to a list without the `@()` step - you just need parentheses to group it: `([System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]($list.GetEnumerator().Foreach({"prefix $PSItem"}))) -is [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]` returns `True`. This kind of casting shouldn't be expensive at all because lists implement the iCollection interface. It doesn't have to rebuild the collection on cast. Fun stuff to dig into!

Comment: @daves I am seeing something interesting. Indeed what comes back is a list, but it's a list of one element. As soon as I replace the simple group with `@()` I get back a list of multiple elements as expected. Is that what you expected, or are we on to something wonky?

Comment: Odd, I can't find a way around that. I guess the `@()` is needed after all.